# How to use Yandex.Metrika in Meteor+React app?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, web-analytics, flow-router, yandex-metrika

I have a Meteor app, all UI components are built with React. I use FlowRouter for routing.

Now I want to add analytics with Yandex.Metrika service.

I found this package for React: https://github.com/narkq/react-yandex-metrika

But I how I have to use it? For what reason do I need `<YM />` component from this example?

```
import {Initializer as YM} from 'react-yandex-metrika';

// Use the initializer to add the script to your page somewhere.
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        // SNIP
          <YM />
        // SNIP
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And where should I initialize the tracker object? I read this:

```
// This is supposed to be executed only in browser and only once.
// Because of that, the most sensible place for this code is right after you javascript bundle.
ym.init([987654321]);
```

But what is javascript bundle and where should I place my `im.init(id)` code?

Actually all what I need is to have funsctions to send data to Metrika, such as `hit` (`pageview` analog rom ga), `reachGoal` and so on.

thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For what reason do I need  component from this example?

You need it to load metrika's main code

How metrika works:
webmaster (you) inserts small piece of js code (loader) to all pages. this code append async script with main code (it's a bit bigger than loader) and create instance of metrika object ('counter') - `new Ya.Metrika(...params)`. Instance will be available in global variable named `yaCounterXXXXX`, where `XXXXX` is your counter's id.

So, `<YM />` component is loader from previous paragraph.

> Actually all what I need is to have funsctions to send data to
>   Metrika, such as hit (pageview analog rom ga), reachGoal and so on.

There is doc about that at the bottom of readme. But I don't see filter by counter id for that methods. Maybe I make a pr to add this functionality. In any case you can use global variable `yaCounterXXXXX` like this `yaCounterXXXXX.hit(url, params)` or `yaCounterXXXXX.reachGoal(goalId, params)`

I hope I helped you.